# Suppress message during compilation

Tags: input, shell-escape

I use a macro with `\write18` and `\@@input`, several times in each page of a large document. But `\@@input` output a message during compilation:

```
(filename)
```

This is very annoying and flood the other relevant informations.

Is there a way to make `\@@input` quiet during compilation in my macro (I use `pdflatex`)?

What I have now is the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\gpNorm}[3][\jobname.eval]{%
  \edef\inp@t{#3}%
  \immediate\write18{gnuplot -e 'set print "#1"; print norm(\inp@t)'}%
  \everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \edef#2{\@@input #1 }%
}
\makeatother
```

I use `write18` to get a computation result from `gnuplot`. But the line with the `\@@input` keep output the `(filename)` message. Can I use something else to read the output of `gnuplot`?

To use it: `\gpNorm{\res}{1}` will assign the result of the computation by `gnuplot` to the macro `\res`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to suppress the

```
(/path/to/filename.tex ...)
```

message on the terminal and in the log file that is generated by TeX every time the `\input` primitive acts by opening a file to be read in (the matching `)` is generated when the end of the file is scanned).

This diagnostic information comes from deep inside TeX and the behavior cannot be changed with macros. Only files read in with the primitives `\font` (when a font is not yet loaded in memory) or with `\openin` and `\read` aren't shown.

---

If you know that the output of the `gnuplot` command is a one liner, then you can read that single line with `\read`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newread\gnuplot@read
\newcommand\gpNorm[3][\jobname.eval]{%
  \immediate\write18{gnuplot -e 'set print "#1"; print norm(#3)'}%
  \openin\gnuplot@read=#1\relax
  \read\gnuplot@read to#2\relax
  \closein\gnuplot@read
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\gpNorm\foo{1+1}

\foo

\end{document}
```

The output in the PDF file is

> 0.977249868051821

while the terminal output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xoff.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian,
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 piedmontese, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian
, serbianc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, u
ppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file xoff.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./xoff.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on xoff.pdf (1 page, 11836 bytes).
Transcript written on xoff.log.
```

---

There is a different way to do it, by exploiting the "pipe input" feature that's available in `pdftex` and `luatex` and should also be included in the next release of `xetex`. If the file name passed to `\input` (which is `\@@input` in LaTeX) starts with `|` (and `-shell-escape` is active), then a process is started with the rest of the name as command line; the standard output is considered to be the input file.

However, in this particular case there's not much to do: if the command line has spaces in it, the whole "file name" must be quoted with double quotes and the inner ones for telling `gnuplot` the output will confuse the parser. A way out could be to have a Bash script, say `xoff-norm.sh`, with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/env gnuplot << EOF
set print "-"
print norm($1)
exit
EOF
```

so that your document can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\gpNorm[2]{%
  \CatchFileEdef#1{"|bash ./xoff-norm.sh #2"}{\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar\m@ne}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\gpNorm\foo{1+1}

\foo
\end{document}
```

I used `catchfile` to avoid reinventing the wheel. In this case, though, *two* processes are started instead of one. Take your pick.

Comment: Can I use `\read`or something else to get the output of a shell command that was executed by using write18 ?

Comment: @Xoff It depends from what you're doing; can you add an example?

Comment: example added just now